# How to delete a line from a text file based on certain criteria

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

Just wondering if anyone would know how to iterate through a csv file and based on a set of rules, delete various lines. Or, alternatively the lines that satisfy the rules can be added to a new output.csv file.

So far I have managed to read the csv file and add each line to an ArrayList. But now I need to apply a set of rules to these lines (preferably using an if statement) and delete lines that do not fit the criteria.

```
package codeTest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String filename = "sample.csv";


    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))){

        stream.forEach(System.out::println);


    try {

        File inputFile = new File("sample.csv");
        File outputFile = new File("Output.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));


        String strLine;
        java.util.ArrayList<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();

        while((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(strLine);
        }

        System.out.println("\nTEST OUTPUT..........................\n");


        Stream<String> lineToRemove = list.stream().filter(x -> x.contains("yes"));



    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
}
```

Any suggestions?
I am in complete coders block if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Files.write` method:

```
List<String> filtered = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).
             filter(x -> x.contains("yes")).collect(Collectors.toList());
Files.write(Paths.get("Output.txt"),filtered);
```

Comment: I'll give it ago within my project constraints and let you know

Comment: Anton Balaniuc: my IDE said "List cannot be resolved as a type"

Comment: I haven't used Java for a year and a half therefore very rusty.

Comment: @PatrickLafferty which IDE do you use?  You need to import `java.util.*`

Comment: I use the Eclipse IDE for all java development

Comment: Your except of code has work perfectly. Thank you.   Have you any idea how to filter integers less than 12 using the same except of code.